# How to cast a list of TBase to a list of TChild where TChild : TBase using KClass<TChild>?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, jvm

I have a list of `TBase` that I know is a list of `TChild`, where `TChild : TBase`. If I only have `KClass<TChild>`, is it possible to cast `List<TBase>` to `List<TChild>`?

```
fun <TChild : BaseType> castList(list: List<BaseType>, clazz: KClass<TChild>): List<TChild> {
    // is this possible?
}
```

I know if `List` wasn't involved, I can cast an instance of `TBase` to `TChild`:

```
clazz.cast(item)
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Looking to avoid reified solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. type assertion.

Remember, generics are figments of the compiler's imagination. The JVM doesn't know what generics is, nor does it care. Most generics is erased (is stripped out and doesn't survive the process of getting turned into a class file). The few parts that remain (generics in signatures) are treated as comments by the JVM. `java.exe` ignores them entirely.

They serve *solely* to make kotlinc/javac generate errors, warnings, and syntax sugar. That's it.

You may make a type assertion. Be aware that these are *unchecked*. You're telling the compiler that you will vouch for the fact that the list in question [A] currently contains solely instances of `TChild` and also [B] that in the future, for the entire duration that this code runs, nothing will change this (no code will end up adding non-TChild refs to this list.

The [B] part is obviously not at all relevant if the list is immutable.

The compiler will just take your word for it. If it turns out you were wrong, you'll get `ClassCastException` on lines that contain zero casts. Because this is a bit bizarre, javac *will* warn you about this, but you can suppress this warning.

Looks like this in java:

```
List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<String> list2 = (List<String>) list1; // warning here
list1.add(5.0); // works.
list2 = (List<String>) list1; // still works. (and warns).
String a = list2.get(0); // look ma, ClassCastException without a cast!
```

to suppress it, `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the local var decl or the method.

In kotlin it looks similar: `list as List<TChild>` to cast it, `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` to suppress the warning.

An alternative is to actually iterate the list and make sure the list actually consists of the right type, throwing a ClassCastException on the spot, instead of injecting into the heap a ticking time bomb that goes off whenever some code touches the list later on:

```
List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();
obj.add(5.0);
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Object o : obj) strings.add((String) o);
```

Naturally, this takes `O(N)` time; any attempt to check the list is going to be `O(N)`, as generics are erased so there's no way to be sure at runtime other than iterating through the lot. It's trivially similar in kotlin.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. As someone from a C# background, JVM generics often trip me up.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really sure that it holds `TChild` objects only and you won't add any other objects to it after the cast (`List` is read-only, not immutable), then you can just do an unchecked cast like this:

```kotlin
fun <TChild : BaseType> castList(list: List<BaseType>, clazz: KClass<TChild>): List<TChild> {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return list as List<TChild>
}
```

If you prefer to actually check types of items while casting then do:

```kotlin
fun <TChild : BaseType> castList(list: List<BaseType>, clazz: KClass<TChild>): List<TChild> {
    return list.map { clazz.cast(it) }
}
```

Just note the second solution creates a copy of the list, so this is not exactly casting. This is important if you intend to modify the original list after casting, because, as I said, `List` is not immutable, but read-only.

Comment: To avoid creating a new list, how about something like `return if (list.all { clazz.isInstance(it) }) list as List<T> else throw InvalidParameterException()`? Maybe a bit more efficient too?